# analyze dataflow block pipline

Tags: tpl-dataflow

In [TPL Dataflow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is there a way to analyse a pipline of dataflow blocks programatically? I would like to find out how blocks are connected by navigating through the links of a pipeline. Where is the information about the links stored (e.g. what are the targets of a source or the sources of a target) and there a public API for it?

Comment: There is no public API for that. Would you be willing/able to use something like a custom `RecordedLinkTo()` instead of the normal `LinkTo()`? If not, I think you would have to resolve to reading private members using reflection.

Comment: Looking at the decompiled sources, reflection seems to be impractical because each block maintains its linked blocks in a different way and I have no way of knowing how custom blocks will handle it. A `RecordedLinkTo()` might be an option (as an extension method and the use of `WeakReference`s)